# How can I stop AspectJ from reweaving?

Tags: java, aspectj

I am attempting to weave new logic into a third-party binary, when doing so, my new advice appears, but it also reweaves all the original advice in the third-party binary. The weaving that was done previously (I'm assuming it was done compile-time) is applied to most of the classes, but for some it doesn't apply the advice back. I am seeing this difference by running the **iajc** task without including the new aspect, decompiling the binaries, and comparing their diff.

How is the previous advice being removed (how does it know what is advice/what isn't), and how can I stop the compiler from removing this previous advice?

In addition, is there any way I can only modify a single class in the third-party binary?

Ideally, I would just add my advice on top of the previous advice (there are no conflicts).

My iajc task:

```
<iajc
    srcdir="../src"
    source="1.7"
    inpath="${build.web.lib}/thirdpartylibrary-original.jar"
    outjar="${build.web.lib}/thirdpartylibrary.jar"
    XlintFile="../src/com/company/utility/helperAspect/ajc.properties">

    <include name="com/company/utility/helperAspect/HelperAspect.aj"/>
    <include name="com/company/utility/Helper.java"/>

    <classpath refid="build.classpath">
    </classpath>
</iajc>
```

Comment: I have an idea what your question might be about, but I want to be sure. So please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) project, ideally on GitHub. I can then take a look and suggest a solution. Sorry, but I cannot debug an Ant snippet out of context. Also, you are asking more than one question, which does not make it any easier.

Comment: I believe I found a workable solution, however, I doubt it would be as elegant or proper as anything you could provide. I believe that this possible solution does provide enough context to understand my question without requiring an example project, but understand if it's not worth your time. Thank you for taking the time to comment and provide insight into how I can ask better questions in the future.

Comment: The problem with your answer is that it is still unclear which problem it is supposed to solve, because the question is no clearer than before. Therefore, it is doubtful whether both Q and A provide much value. I am more confused than before, and I would have liked to help you solve your problem, if only I could understand and reproduce it. My feeling after reading your answer is, however, that it might be more complicated and "hacky" than necessary. Just because it works for you now, does not mean you should leave it in that state. This type of hack tends to be hard to maintain over time.

Comment: But in a way, this is the perfect example of why I always disliked Ant and scripted builds in general. 

Answer (score 0):

## Possible Solution

This solution won't apply for everyone and is really a roundabout way of reaching the end goal. Instead of running the aspect across the entire third party binary, you can pull out the class(es) you want to modify then repackage them with the original jar.

Again, this is a roundabout solution and if the third-party aspects modify the file your aspect modifies, this won't solve your problem.

```xml
<!-- Rename original thirdpartylibrary.jar -->
<move failonerror="true" file="${build.web.lib}/thirdpartylibrary.jar" tofile="${build.web.lib}/thirdpartylibrary-original.jar" />

<!-- Create a jar containing only the classes required for the AspectJ Weaving -->
<zip destfile="${build.web.lib}/thirdpartylibrary-onlyModificationClass.jar" >
    <zipfileset src="${build.web.lib}/thirdpartylibrary-original.jar" includes="**/ClassForModification.class" />
</zip>

<!-- Create a jar containing the weaved classes -->
<iajc
        srcdir="../src"
        source="1.7"
        inpath="${build.web.lib}/thirdpartylibrary-onlyModificationClass.jar"
        outjar="${build.web.lib}/thirdpartylibrary-onlyModificationClass-withTooling.jar"
        XlintFile="../src/com/company/utility/helperAspect/ajc.properties"
>
    <!-- Inclusions for Helper tool -->
    <include name="com/company/utility/helperAspect/HelperAspect.aj"/>
    <include name="com/company/utility/Helper.java"/>

    <classpath refid="build.classpath">
    </classpath>
</iajc>

<!-- Combine the original thirdpartylibrary.jar with the new weaved files -->
<zip destfile="${build.web.lib}/thirdpartylibrary.jar" >
    <zipfileset src="${build.web.lib}/thirdpartylibrary-onlyModificationClass-withTooling.jar"/>
    <zipfileset src="${build.web.lib}/thirdpartylibrary-original.jar" excludes="**/ClassForModification.class"  />
</zip>

<!-- Delete temporary jar artifacts created during the weaving process -->
<delete file="${build.web.lib}/thirdpartylibrary-original.jar"/>-->
<delete file="${build.web.lib}/thirdpartylibrary-onlyModificationClass.jar"/>
<delete file="${build.web.lib}/thirdpartylibrary-onlyModificationClass-withTooling.jar"/>
```

### In summary:

1. I pulled out the class that I needed to weave from the third-party jar, including required Aspect classes (dependencies are included since this jar is in the build classpath)
2. Run the iajc ant task, weaving my advice into the class, creating a jar.
3. Remove the class from the third-party jar, and add in the classes from the new jar, creating a combined modified jar.

Comment: I suspect a better solution would have been to use Overweaving